# Import tree data with Sitecore Rocks

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I've just tried out a nice feature in `Sitecore Rocks` which is to import data & create a tree in the content tree, using the `Query Analyzer`, following this [documentation](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/master/docs/QueryAnalyzer/QueryAnalyzerSamples.md).

The data in the text file will be in this format:

```
* News|/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder
** 2019|/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder
*** Month|/sitecore/templates/Month|12
```

But, it will only create the items in the tree structure. Is there a way where we can also populate the field values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want to do is not possible with a `Tree Import` - that only creates the items, you would then have to get the items and populate fields after.

#### CSV Import:

Alternatively you could use the [CVS import source](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/master/docs/QueryAnalyzer/QueryAnalyzerSamples.md#csv-import-source). This allows you to populate fields at the time of creation:

```
import csv
" 
,
@ItemName, Title, Text
Home, Sitecore, "Welcome to Sitecore"
"
```

In that example, it is setting a default template, and then the columns define the properties of each item.

#### Update items after a Tree Import

One more option would be to update the items after the tree import by using the `update` command in the Query Analyzer:

```
update set 
  @Title = "Welcome to Sitecore", 
  @Text = "Hello" 
from /sitecore/content/Home
```

This seems a little more effort to write out, but would give you what you need.